# SQL: get avg values with null

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with the following query. It isn't showing me wines that have pairings without grade (null value) and I need to show all the wines, even those without an AVG grade. How can I do that?

```
SELECT wineid
     , wine_name
     , winetype_name
     , wine_img
     , producer_name
     , region_name
     , sponsored
     , recipe_name
     , recipeid
     , grade_name
     , nota
  from
     ( select wine.id as wineid
            , wine_name
            , winetype_name
            , wine_img
            , producer.producer_name AS producer_name
            , region_name
            , sponsored
            , recipe_name     
            , recipe.id as recipeid
            , **round(avg(grade_id),0) as nota**
        from wine
            , producer          
            , winetype
            , region
            , recipe
            , rating
            , pairing
        where wine.id = pairing.wine_id 
         and wine.winetype_id = winetype.id 
         and wine.producer_id = producer.id 
         and wine.region_id = region.id 
         and recipe.id = pairing.recipe_id 
         and rating.pairing_id = pairing.id 
        group 
            by wineid
             , wine_name
             , recipe_name) as temp
     , grade
 where grade.id = temp.nota 
  order 
    by sponsored desc
     , nota desc;
```

Comment: What database do you use ? Also, some example data would be great.

Comment: Relational. Is that you are asking?

Comment: No, is it Oracle ? MySQL...

Comment: Sorry. MySql...

Comment: I have other issue here: rating.pairing_id = pairing.id. 

Wines without rating aren't even on that Rating table. Is there any way to counter this?

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  This may not fix your query but it will make it more likely that someone will answer your question.

Comment: You learned sql pre-1992?

Comment: @Strawberry isn't today January 21st 1991?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use implicit joins (with a comma in the `from` clause)! Instead, use modern, explicit joins (with the `on` keyword). Not only are they the de-facto standard, but also it's easy to change them to `left join`, which seems to be what you need here.

Here is an updated version of your query that uses the modern join syntax; I changed a few joins to left joins (you might need to adapt that more, since without seeing actual sample data it is almost impossible to guess which joins should be changed exactly):

```
select
    wineid, 
    wine_name, 
    winetype_name, 
    wine_img, 
    producer_name, 
    region_name, 
    sponsored, 
    recipe_name, 
    recipeid, 
    grade_name, 
    nota
from 
    (
        select 
            wine.id as wineid, 
            wine_name, 
            winetype_name, 
            wine_img, 
            producer.producer_name AS producer_name, 
            region_name, 
            sponsored, 
            recipe_name, 
            recipe.id as recipeid, 
            round(avg(grade_id), 0) as nota
            from 
            wine, 
            inner join producer on wine.producer_id = producer.id  
            inner join winetype on wine.winetype_id = winetype.id
            inner join region on wine.region_id = region.id 
            left join pairing on wine.id = pairing.wine_id 
            left join recipe on recipe.id = pairing.recipe_id 
            left join rating rating.pairing_id = pairing.id 
        group by 
            wine.id,
            wine_name, 
            winetype_name, 
            wine_img, 
            producer.producer_name, 
            region_name, 
            sponsored, 
            recipe_name, 
            recipe.id
    ) as temp 
    left join grade on grade.id = temp.nota 
order by 
    sponsored desc, 
    nota desc;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked out.

I learned that way but thanks to your input ill pay more attention to that type of construction. Its easier to interpretate and to modify like u said.

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? @Downvoter, please elaborate so I possibly can improve the answer.

Comment: it is totally misleading to put downvote without proper explanation, I didn't find any reason for downvoting

Comment: Now another question. I was using Jquery filters with my previous query. Once I selected a filter a condition was added to the query. Just like this: 

 if (!empty($_GET["region_id"]))  {
      $region_id= $_GET["region_id"];
      $conditions[] = " and wine.region_id LIKE '%$region_id'";
    }

Is that still possible with this query construction?

Answer (score 1):

First thing you should know is that it is very difficult to help you without any data. We can only guess. So please do check this few things and edit your questions after you have checked them.

**1.**

I do not know what kind of data do you have but do check this relation:

```
where grade.id = temp.nota
```

because the `temp.nota` in your code is calculated as :

```
round(avg(grade_id),0) as nota
```

and I do not believe that the grade.id the same as this calculated value. It is a bad join I believe.

**2.**

Please do not use JOIN like this:

```
as temp, grade where grade.id = temp.nota
```

do it like this:

```
as temp left join grade on grade.id = temp.nota
```

Comment: When the query was constructed I forgot to take into account that some pairings wouldn't have rating. Now its only displaying to me those that have at least 1 rating. 

Thanks for the other inputs!

Comment: @Flemingpt, Please do have in mind that I do not know nothing about your data. So. When you write the answers or comments lets keep it simple.  Please give me some example data from your column grade.id. Is it like1, 2, 3 or ?

Comment: Yes, grade.id has numeric values. 

Another user already helped me with the query. Now I just have to see how I can add conditions to this query, for instance, filtering with a jquery function for a specific region, producer, or something.